# Where should I ask a question about networking

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have a problem with my router (Networking) and was wondering where would be a good place to ask my question? Obviously not on stackoverflow =).

Sorry this question is short.

Answer (score 4):

Configuation problems can be posted on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

From the superuser.com FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about computer hardware, computer software, **personal and home computer networking**

If your problems are administrator related I would recommend [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). FAQ:

> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems **in a professional capacity**.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a list of the different stack exchange sites for reference](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)

I personally would ask on either Super User or Server Fault, depending on the scale of your networking problem, but you should have a look over that list to see if there might be something more applicable